# Row number from calculation query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with users stats. To make it simple, it looks like this:

```
id  nick        kills   deaths
1   Misiek      25      20
2   Astma       22      18
3   4i60r       20      32
4   Heatseeker  45      45
```

To show what I need to query I prepared working SQL Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)+1 as `rank` FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, (kills/deaths) as kdr FROM `killerzy`) as b WHERE kdr > (SELECT (kills/deaths) as kdr FROM `killerzy` WHERE nick="4i60r")) as test
```

Result of this query is:

```
rank
4
```

To show how kdr's are calculated I used:

```
SELECT *, (kills/deaths) as kdr FROM `killerzy` WHERE 1
```

It produces:

```
id nick        kills   deaths  kdr
1   Misiek      25      20      1.2500
2   Astma       22      18      1.2222
3   4i60r       20      32      0.6250
4   Heatseeker  45      45      1.0000
```

## Question

**My question is:** do mysql or postgresql database have ready function to get 'rank' for player without writing 3 nested queries? I think about something like:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() FROM (SELECT (kills/deaths) as kdr FROM killerzy ORDER BY kdr DESC) WHERE nick = "4i60r"
```

It look more logical than 3 nested queries.

I see that it's hard to understand so simple question. Here it comes in other version: Does MySQL or PostgreSQL have function that can return on which position in resultset is row, that I need. Something like "GET_POSITION WHERE".
It's weird that my question is put on hold when someone got the point and answered good - simple JOIN query that looks good and executes fast.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Other understood, but I added clear question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you seem to want is a simple ranking query. In MySQL's case it would be something like;

```
SELECT *, (kills/deaths) kdr, @rank := @rank + 1 rank 
FROM `killerzy`, (SELECT @rank := 0) r 
ORDER BY kdr DESC
```

In PostgreSQL, you can simply use `RANK() OVER()`;

```
SELECT *, 1.0*kills/deaths as kdr, 
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY 1.0*kills/deaths DESC) rank
FROM killerzy;
```

Sadly SQLfiddle seems tired, so can't add a fiddle.

EDIT: For a single player, you can do it with a `LEFT JOIN`;

```
SELECT me.*, me.kills/me.deaths kdr, 1+COUNT(other.id) rank 
FROM killerzy me 
LEFT JOIN killerzy other 
  ON me.kills/me.deaths < other.kills/other.deaths 
WHERE me.nick='4i60r';
```

Comment: But it's for all. I need result for only one player (to show it in-game on player join).

Comment: @Misiek Added a MySQL version of that too.

Comment: Last query works like a charm and looks good.